# How to save a review or rating with Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, rating

I'm using the library android material app rating (https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-app-rating)
and I don't know how to save in SharedPreferences that the user has already done the review or rating.

I can save information in SharedPreferences if it's a TextView, but in this case I have no idea what to do.

**Can you help me?**

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to save the info whether the user has rated you app:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyShared", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("HasUserRating", true);
editor.apply();
```

Read back from `SharedPreferences` that the user has or has not rated:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyShared", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean hasRated = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("HasUserRating", false);
```

(Note: This will return false if the `SharedPreferences` key "HasUserRating" is not present.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the callbacks within `RatingDialogListener` to save a value to SharedPreferences. Check for the existence of that SharedPreferences value prior to displaying the dialog.